# How to fire one event when we release the click on a kivy switch item?

Tags: python, events, widget, kivy

Goal: when I click then release the click on the switch widget, it fires me an event on the release.

Problem: I used the on_touch_down() Switch method but:

- it release 2 event on the release of the click and not only one.
- when I release and it shows "off", it says "True" and it shows "False" when it's on "on" !

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


KV = '''
MyGridLayout:
    Switch:
        id: switch_ecs
        on_touch_up:
            root.on_switch("ecs")
'''

class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_switch(self,element_id):
        print(self.ids["switch_" + element_id].active)

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.screen



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy has some obscure logic that results in touch up events getting dispatched twice to some widgets (like `Buttons` and `Switches`). The fix for your code is to use a different trigger for your `on_switch()` method. You can use:

```
    on_touch_down:
        root.on_switch("ecs")
```

or:

```
    on_active:
        root.on_switch("ecs")
```

Comment: "obscur logic" and not logical behavior seems like a bug to me :/ but thanks for the answer ! ```on_active``` do exactly what I need ! I don't know why they didn't precise this method on the doc here https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.switch.html